# Deactivate physics for touching objects

Tags: physics

I have a simple scene with falling dominos. Each domino has "deactivation" turned on with crazy high velocity values.

Unfortunately, after dominos falling as expected, that don't lay still, but rather continue slow spreading around until all dominos are laying on the ground separately.

I tried to set ground and domino frictions to 1. No improvement.

How can I deactivate physics for slow moving objects even if the are touched by other slow moving objects?

My .blend file:

[image]

UPDATED Version:

[image]

Instructions:

- Press space-bar to see the animation, wait at least up to frame 500 to see the spreading
- You can regenerate the dominos from the template domino object by going to the "script" tab and run "main.py" script. All dominos will be deleted and recreated from the template domino object.

Comment: Just from the information "a simple scene with falling dominos" it's hard to tell what's going wrong. And I don't know how high "crazy high velocity values" are. I only know if I create a simple scene they lay still even without deactivation. So maybe it would be best if you upload your file here https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit your file into the question.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. Please, check out my .blend file :)

Comment: You can force the friction (plane and dominos) to a higher value than 1.

Comment: There are a lot of things I see from the start. First, in many situations the most important thing: the scale is not applied. That's especially for simulations critical. But you cannot simply apply it because all objects are linked, you have to make them single user objects. After the scale is applied, the speed is too high. You can also increase the substeps and solver iterations in the Rigid Body World settings. I'd also increase friction on the objects and set bounciness on dominos and plane to 0. And this might be correct size, but in general the physics work better with larger objects.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann great tips! Fixed scaling, small size and increased substeps and solver iterations. Substeps and iterations fixed the spreading problem. But deactivation still not work. After each domino has fallen, the simulation remains slow ... Any ideas? ("speed is too high" what do you mean? Speed in the rigid body world? If it is set to 1, the dominos are fallen unnaturally slow)

Comment: Yes, that speed... it was set to 4, after I applied the scale it looked much too fast (at least on my computer - is your playback speed reaching realtime? Don't know your specs). Maybe change the collision shape to _Convex Hull_. In theory _Box_ should be more accurate though, but anyway. And when I have an animation coming to an almost halt, I simulate only to this frame - then all stops. You simulate 10,000 frames - why?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I didn't applied scale, but as you mentioned made objects larger. Anyway scale is 1. Speed is still 4 and it looks natural. I uploaded current version of the file. Could you please look, why physics doesn't deactivate on fallen dominos? I will have 1000+ dominos in the scene. I can't simulate everything for every frame... Huge thanks!

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann any idea, how to get physics to deactivate for fallen dominos? Thank you :)